# Coupon code to unlock free shipping (magento)

Tags: magento

I am looking for a way to unlock free shipping in frontend.

Via a code tweak we now show this in backend always. But not on frontend.

What we would like is that if a user enters a coupon code they option to ship for free is shown on the backend.

What code need I pull into the shipping templates to add an if statement that if certain coupon code has been entered that free shipping shows up

- (workaround) currently free shipping coupon code not working in combination with other coupon code for 10 $ discount

thanks, Sean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some coding has been done on the following location

https://github.com/seansan/Magento_SNH_extensions

Answer (score 0):

The first step is to create a Shopping Cart Price Rule with your required coupon code. If you just want to apply free shipping to the order you can set that as an action in the rule.

If you want to show the free shipping option *only* if this discount is applied, however, don't put any actions on the rule and instead use `Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getCouponCode();` to check the applied code in the checkout template.

I've just run a quick test using this code in 1.7 and it works great.

Comment: Super duper. PS!! Dont you think this solution would be an even better solution than a difficult rule (that hardly works) for free shipping. Just add a box / option per cart rule that says: enable free shipping option YES/NO

Comment: also = fyi/we are difficulty setting up multiple coupons (1 for money discount + 1 for shipping) ... supposedly magento doest support two coupon codes

Comment: First off, I'm glad my response helped you out! To be honest I can't remember (and haven't a suitable environment at this moment to test) whether Magento does actually show the free shipping option as well as applying it to the order, assuming it is normally disabled and has been applied to the order via promo rules. This would be logical, since the customer may wish to select next day delivery instead of free 7 day shipping..

Comment: Yeah unfortunately Magento only allows one discount code to be entered at once. Bit of an oversight IMHO, perhaps there's a module available to change this?